# Reload a Letsencrypt certificate on Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, lets-encrypt

I'm running Nginx within a Docker container and I need to reload its configuration periodically to pick up the updated **Letsecnrypt** SSL certificate.

In the `docker-compose` file I have the followings

```
command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
```

Which, as far as I know, should reload the configuration and restart Nginx every 6 hours. however, it doesn't work. The SSL certificate is renewed but it's not picked up by Nginx.

Any ideas of how I can correctly reload the Letsencrypt SSL certificate every few hours?

**Update 08/08/19**

From my understanding, the issue is related to the fact that the certificate files I mount into the container are actually symlinks and symlinks don't play nicely with Docker.

Answer (score 5):

These solutions involving a while loop inside the `command` of `docker-composer.yml` have a fundamental flaw regarding signal handling.  The shell script is now the main process which receives the signal for shutting down, but it won't be properly forwarded to nginx.  This causes the container to not shut down immediately on `docker-compose down`, and then it runs into the default 10 seconds timeout before it is killed.  See [Why do my services take 10 seconds to recreate or stop?](https://docs.docker.com/compose/faq/#why-do-my-services-take-10-seconds-to-recreate-or-stop)

Here's a solution that leaves nginx as the main process:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx
        volumes:
            - ./99-autoreload.sh:/docker-entrypoint.d/99-autoreload.sh
    # add certbot container here
```

And then create a file `99-autoreload.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
while :; do
    # Optional: Instead of sleep, detect config changes and only reload if necessary.
    sleep 6h
    nginx -t && nginx -s reload
done &
```

Don't forget to `chmod 755 99-autoreload.sh`, otherwise it won't be executed.

A more advanced setup would be to actually detect change and only reload if necessary.  This can be done with `inotifywait` for example.

Comment: Since I was wondering how this works: The nginx docker image is set up to execte all scripts in the `/docker-entrypoint.d/` directory during start.

Answer (score 4):

This should work if you have the ability to use the host's crontab for scheduling:

`0 */6 * * * docker exec <nginx_container_id> nginx -s reload`

via [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45261250/2343739)

And then don't specify the custom command with the wait and reload that you tried in your question. Just orchestrate the `reload` from the host's cron.

If you can't use the host's cron in your environment, however, you'll need another solution...

Comment: I'd rather find a solution that doesn't rely on the host.

Comment: If certbot is also running in a docker container, then what? The host's cron can be used to start that certbot container, but how can you tell when it's done its job, and that you need to reload the nginx container?